# Sqlite encryption for Android

Tags: android, api, sqlite, encryption, android-ndk

I have an Android app that has been already developed using SQLite.
The DB is quite large (over 100 Megs) so it can be deployed only on the SD card.
The data inside the DB is sensitive so for this reason we need to encrypt the DB.
The default SQLite binary on the phone does not allow encryption or to add a plug in (extensions).
I manage to compile the SQLite using NDK with the encryption extension (I am calling this SQLiteS - from secure) but I still need to figure out how to copy the Sqlite API and bind it to the new SQLiteS binary. 
The idea is to not change the already developed code using the SQLite default API excepting the package name.
Any idea of how can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

Tryp getting a native jdbcsqlite driver onto Android.
which makes sqlite3_* calls(JNI).

Use the aapt tool to link the library(sqliteS) into the .apk file.

Also, you can change the sqlite3_* names(in SQLiteS.so you built) so that it doesnt refer to sqlite.so file provided by android.

Let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer for your question, but you could try the (free, open source) [H2 database](http://h2database.com). It supports data file encryption as well. There are some disadvantages however, for example some operations are quite a bit slower. You would need to use the JDBC API because the SQLite / Android database API is not yet supported. Disclaimer: I'm one of the H2 committers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I have a quick question, do you have any idea of how fast/slow is H2 compared with SQLite ? I am doing mainly Selects but the tables are big (> 700K records). Using SQLite we get the results in less then a second, can H2 handle the same amount of data ?
Also, does H2 works on BlackBerry ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't give you a good answer about the performance - you would have to test it yourself. H2 does not work on a BlackBerry.

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlCipher. SQLCipher is an open source extension to SQLite that provides transparent 256-bit AES encryption of database files.
See http://sqlcipher.net/